# Invoking Swift code from C

Tags: c, interop, swift

How do I call Swift code from C or C++? I can only find documentation for the other way around.

If all else fails, I'll wrap my code in an Objective-C class and use it for interop, but I was wondering if there would be another way.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode automatically generates a "<yourmodule>-Swift.h" header, which you can simply import from your Obj-C code (it has to be Obj-C, since Swift classes are exported as Obj-C classes). See [Importing Swift into Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_83).